# Regex with .find(), no results

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I'm trying to change `id` and `name` attributes on a page. The code I'm using is this:

```
var img = new RegExp( 'id*="launch_pad_image_slide_\d"', g ) ;
$('.slider-data').each(function(){
    $(this).find(img).attr( 'id', 'random stuff' );
});
```

The assumption is the `.find` function should pick up the whole `id` inside:

```
id="launch_pad_image_slide_2"
```

...but it does not work.

5 hours on this, and burned out. Suggestions? Basically every time a field is deleted, jQuery has to loop through them and number their `id`/`name` attributes properly to avoid doubles.

Comment: What @VisioN has posted should fix your problem, but for future reference using incremental attributes is never an elegant solution as it leads to problems like you've just experienced. Instead, use elements with the same class or name and traverse them, either through the DOM or as an array.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Where is your bow? :)

Comment: @VisioN check out the hats in the Winter Bash :D

Comment: Out of curiosity, where did you get the idea from that you could regular expressions as a selector?

Comment: Thanks. Good solutions you've gave, but maybe the whole idea can be simplified as you've mentioned. Felix King...the idea just came to me. Sometimes I think way more out the box than what is appropriate.

Answer (score 10):

jQuery selector doesn't support regex syntax. However, you may use [Attribute Starts With Selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/):

```
$(this).find("[id^='launch_pad_image_slide_']").prop("id", "random stuff");
```

Another way is to [`filter`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) the elements:

```
$(this).find("[id]").filter(function() {
    return /^launch_pad_image_slide_\d$/.test(this.id);
}).prop("id", "random stuff");
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
    $('img').each(function(){
           if ($(this).attr('id').indexOf("launch_pad_image_slide_") >= 0)
               $(this).attr('id',Math.random());
    });
```